# On the Goldbach conjecture

Tags: soft-question, goldbachs-conjecture

As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture), Goldbach conjecture has been shown to hold for all integers less than $4\times 10^{18}$ since 2012. Has it been verified for some larger bounded integers ?

Comment: It's always hard to prove the negative, but the answer seems to be that there have been no further computational efforts.

Comment: I am pretty sure that single numbers and ranges with larger numbers have been tested, but apparently there is no larger gap-free range that has been verified.